# Installing wine with homebrew

Tags: mac, install, macports, homebrew, wine

So, I am running a bit of a different install. Here's the background:

- I have installed wine before with MacPorts.
- Later, I decided to install homebrew.
- Then, wine didn't work so I tried `brew install wine`, but that didn't work.

So I try `brew install wine`:

```
zsh: correct 'wine' to '.wine' [nyae]? n
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
==> Installing wine dependency: libicns
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/icns/libicns-0.8.1.t
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libicns-0.8.1.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libicns/0.8.1
==> make install
      _WritePNGImage in icns2png.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [icns2png] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Error: libicns did not build
Logs: /Users/scott/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libicns/
Help: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

Then, I try again with MacPorts:

```
zsh: correct 'wine' to '.wine' [nyae]? n
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for wine
--->  Dependencies to be installed: apple-gcc42 cctools ld64 gcc_select bison gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses m4 xz flex fontconfig freetype bzip2 zlib pkgconfig gst-plugins-base gnome-vfs desktop-file-utils glib2 perl5 perl5.12 gdbm popt gconf dbus-glib dbus gtk-doc docbook-xml docbook-xml-4.1.2 docbook-xml-4.2 xmlcatmgr docbook-xml-4.3 docbook-xml-4.4 docbook-xml-4.5 docbook-xml-5.0 docbook-xsl gnome-doc-utils intltool gnome-common p5.12-getopt-long p5.12-pathtools p5.12-scalar-list-utils p5.12-xml-parser iso-codes libxslt libxml2 py27-libxml2 python27 db46 libedit openssl python_select sqlite3 rarian getopt gtk2 atk gobject-introspection cairo libpixman libpng xorg-xcb-util xorg-libxcb xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto xrender xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-renderproto gdk-pixbuf2 jasper jpeg tiff hicolor-icon-theme pango Xft2 shared-mime-info xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXext autoconf help2man p5.12-locale-gettext automake libtool xorg-util-macros xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto orbit2 libidl policykit eggdbus gnome-mime-data gstreamer gzip texinfo libtheora libvorbis libogg orc xorg-libice xorg-libsm lcms mesa makedepend xorg-dri2proto xorg-glproto xorg-libXmu xorg-libXt xorg-libXxf86vm xorg-xf86vidmodeproto
Error: Requested variants "+llvm31+universal" do not match original selection "+llvm31".
Please use the same variants again, perform 'port clean ld64' or specify the force option (-f).
Error: Failed to install ld64
Please see the log file for port ld64 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_ld64/ld64/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: apple-gcc42 cctools ld64 gcc_select bison gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses m4 xz flex fontconfig freetype bzip2 zlib pkgconfig gst-plugins-base gnome-vfs desktop-file-utils glib2 perl5 perl5.12 gdbm popt gconf dbus-glib dbus gtk-doc docbook-xml docbook-xml-4.1.2 docbook-xml-4.2 xmlcatmgr docbook-xml-4.3 docbook-xml-4.4 docbook-xml-4.5 docbook-xml-5.0 docbook-xsl gnome-doc-utils intltool gnome-common p5.12-getopt-long p5.12-pathtools p5.12-scalar-list-utils p5.12-xml-parser iso-codes libxslt libxml2 py27-libxml2 python27 db46 libedit openssl python_select sqlite3 rarian getopt gtk2 atk gobject-introspection cairo libpixman libpng xorg-xcb-util xorg-libxcb xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto xrender xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-renderproto gdk-pixbuf2 jasper jpeg tiff hicolor-icon-theme pango Xft2 shared-mime-info xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXext autoconf help2man p5.12-locale-gettext automake libtool xorg-util-macros xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto orbit2 libidl policykit eggdbus gnome-mime-data gstreamer gzip texinfo libtheora libvorbis libogg orc xorg-libice xorg-libsm lcms mesa makedepend xorg-dri2proto xorg-glproto xorg-libXmu xorg-libXt xorg-libXxf86vm xorg-xf86vidmodeproto
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port wine failed
```

How do I get wine to install on the Mac preferably with Homebrew?

Comment: I filed an issue with the brew devs to get this resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like they've already got [a workaround:](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/15478)

```
brew rm libpng
brew install libpng --universal
```

Then `brew install wine`. Worked for me a few moments ago. See the linked github issue for more details.

Answer (score 4):

It may also tell you that jpeg was not installed with `--universal`. You can just do: `brew rm jpeg` ...and then: `brew install jpeg --universal` to re-install it universally. Not sure if there are other dependencies or not...But that's one that I got.

Answer (score 3):

Note that there might be quite a few dependencies you have to remove and reinstall with `--universal` for it to compile, depending on how many of them you have already installed without the universal flag (I had to remove/reinstall jpeg, libtool, libusb, libpng, and libtiff).